# R: Retrieve dataframe from given column name

Tags: r, dataframe

In a function I want the input to be a column from a data frame and then within the function I need to be able to refer to the entire data frame.

So the input would be for instance `HEWC$Mostly`.CA and within the function I need to extract and work with `HEWC`.

How do I refer to the entire data frame from the given column?

Comment: Then you should make the data frame the input to the function.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to give the whole data frame as an input ?

Comment: For user simplicity, but I decided to go ahead and add it as part of the input.